# Spontaneous Reputation Loss

Tags: support, reputation, voting

I had a 308 reputation about thirty minutes ago, and someone has spontaneously down-voted at least four of my answers, and voted to delete them. I expect that this will happen more, and I would like to fix it. How can I report this?

Comment: I deleted it because there was a delete request and someone had downvoted at least four of my posts, and pressed the delete button, to be a troll. I wasn't implying that it was you, and I have no idea who it was... That's why I put the tag troll-report here, and why I deleted the posts so that I could get the rep back and make the tag.

Comment: You really don't want mods to review votes. I mean, that isn't even a feasible option since votes are (correctly) secret, but even if it were, the last thing you should be asking for is for some rando to be the arbitrer of how you get to cast your vote. Mods are not anything special, they're just regular users and just as likely to make the wrong call as anyone else. And I say this as a current mod on [unix.se] and ex mod here on [ubuntu.se]. The better approach is to trust in the broader community of users. After all, three downvotes is nothing that cannot be undone by three upvotes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fun fact, when you get serial downvoted or attacked by reputation, the system is kinda smart.

Here's what your reputation tracker says:

[image]

[image]

Downvotes on your posts which were then removed led to automatic reverts of those downvotes, and later there were more reverting of the downvotes or reputation loss for "Serial Downvoting".

This shows you that 'trolls' who serial downvote someone get handled by the system, moderators don't even have to do anything about that.

So, I wouldn't fret about small fluctuations - they happen all the time, but even this being said, the system is doing its job.  So don't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for that! I wish I had known that yesterday... Would make me less... "insecure," if you catch my drift.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't down-vote any of your posts. I did make a suggestion to improve one...before you deleted it.

You're absolutely right that it's awful when somebody is clearly being mean. Many of us have received that kind of cowardly attack.

However, as somebody who has lived through similar dark days, I encourage you keep contributing and to let the current system work.

Your contributions will be recognized and rewarded without needing to make moderators review hundreds of extra posts each day.

Those trolls do get bored and wander away. Some do indeed get banned (the moderators don't make a lot of noise when that occurs).